# how to set a variable in module and get it in theme

Tags: 7, theming

i want set a variable in module and use it in my theme,
(except variable_set and variable_get way.)

for instance . in module file

```
      if(in_array(arg(1),$ex))
      {
//      set a variable
      }
```

in theme file

```
if(//variable)
{
echo '<div class=d7></div>';
}
```

thank you so much for help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOWEVER:

You should really look into the various _preprocess() hooks.  From further commentary below, I am thinking that's where you should be doing all this.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

If you don't want to use the system wide `variable_set()` or `variable_get()` you can always set a variable in the global `$_SESSION` array that would be seen by the current logged in user only, eg,

```
if ( // whatever ) {
  $_SESSION['MYMODULE_variable_name']= // whatever
}
```

SUPER DUPER OVER SIMPLIFIED ADDITION:

```
function MYMODULE_foo($value=NULL) {
  static $bar;

  if ($value) {
     $bar=$value;
  }

  return $bar;
}
```

accomplishes it inside your module, eg, you can do:

```
MYMODULE_foo('this is cool');
```

and then in your theme do:

```
$baz=MYMODULE_foo();
```

Comment: hi and thank you . i use from hook_node_load,but i don`t khonw how use from your code in this hook . i need help more for this Problem

Comment: in MYMODULE.module, you would just put the _foo() function, and then anyplace you want to set the variable you would call the first example, and anywhere you wanted to get the variable, you would call the second example.  Or, you could use the _SESSION way first suggested anywhere.